# Parsing a function call using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to parse a function call:

```
foo(arg1, arg2 ...)
```

to match for `foo`, `arg1`, `arg2`.  But the issue I'm having is, `arg1` may be `bar(x1, x2)` with commas inside.

When I use [this tool](https://pythex.org) with `([\w]+)\((.*?)\)$` as my regex and `foo(bar(2,'a'), bas())` as my test case, I'm able to capture `foo` and the entire line of arguments `bar(2,'a'), bas()`, but I'm not sure how to capture the arguments separately.

I would like to capture:

- `foo`
- `bar(2,'a')`
- `bas()`

**How do I revise my python regex to capture these argument separately?**

Comment: You could use `split(",")`... Or did you want to do this all with regex

Comment: @12944qwerty No, split would fail due to internal commas in `bar(2,'a')`.

Comment: Should this be done with two arguments only? Or should it be dynamic?

Comment: @12944qwerty it should capture any number of arguments, separated by commas and I would like to do this purely in python regex, if possible.

Comment: Regex is not the tool for this, or any type of recursive/arbitrarily-nested structure - a single regex expression cannot parse recursively (this is why regex cannot adequately parse HTML). Using [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse the string would probably be more useful.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy good idea - I will take a look at `ast` - ty

Comment: The `re` module cannot handle recursive regular expressions; however, the third party [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library can.

Comment: @RootTwo interesting - I'll take a look - ty!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `([\w]+)\((.*?), (.*?)\)$`. It will work for two arguments. See the testing [here](https://regex101.com/r/Umsdg0/1)

- `(.*?)` - finds the shortest possible argument
- `,`  - `,`  (separates the argument)
- `(.*?)` - finds the second argument

If you want it to be dynamic with 1+ number of arguments, you can use the following regex: `([\w]+)\((.*?)(?:, (.*?))*\)$`. See the testing [here](https://regex101.com/r/fS4Mlw/1)

- `(.*?)` - finds the shortest first possible argument
- `(?:, (.*?))*` - finds the next 0-n number of `, (.*?)`

  - `,`  - matches `,`  literally but does not capture
  - `(.*?)` - matches another argument

Comment: This looks very close to working!  It seems to fail for the case with no arguments, though.  I'll play with this to see if we can get closer.

Comment: @kfmfe04 Question, why doesn't this work with functions with no arguments? It returns two groups: the function name and nothing (for the the arguments).